# Why doesn't happen re-composition when the state is updated?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

So I try to understand, and learn compose with MVI archtecture.

In my viewModel I created a StateFlow object:

```
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(UserManagerState())
    val state = _state.asStateFlow()
```

This is the state class:

```
data class UserManagerState(
    val userList: List<UserWithRoleView> = emptyList(),
    val shouldCallUpdate: Boolean = false,
    var successMessage: String? = null
) {
}
```

The problem is, when I update 1 property in the list, it doesn't trigger re-composition.

I update the state like this:

```
    private fun changeUserRole(user: UserWithRoleView, role: RoleEnum) {
        val s = _state.value.userList.toMutableList()
        s.find { it.id == user.id }?.apply {
            newRole = role
        }

        _state.value =
            _state.value.copy(
                userList = s
            )
    }
```

Firstly I tried to update only just one property, but is didn't work. After that I tried it in so many ways, but it seems, it doesn't work properly. I also checked the state after the update, so it seems good.

The logic is simple,

I have a screen, where I have a LazyColumn, this screen contains a button, which is invisible, and the list changes should make it visible.

Compose class:

```
@Composable
fun UserManagerScreen(
    modifier: Modifier,
    viewModel: UserManagerViewModel = hiltViewModel<UserManagerViewModel>()
) {
    val state by viewModel.state.collectAsState()

    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        LazyColumn {
            items(state.userList, key = {
                it.id
            }) { user ->
                UserWithRoleItem(userWithRoleView = user) { newRole ->
                    viewModel.updateEvent(UserManagerEvent.OnRoleChanged(user, newRole))
                }
            }
        }
        
        val shouldShowSaveButton = 
            state
            .userList
            .any { userWithRoleView ->  
                userWithRoleView.role.name != userWithRoleView.newRole.name
            }
        
        if(shouldShowSaveButton) {
            Button(onClick = {
                viewModel.updateEvent(UserManagerEvent.UpdateUsers)
            }) {
                Text(text = "Modify")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I sure I do something in the wrong way, because if I set an emptyList() to the state in the update function, re-composition happens, and the LazyColumn won't show anything which is good.

I also tried something. I added a simple bool property to the my state class, and I updated this property at the same time, when I updated the list. Finally it caused re-composition. So, what is the problem with my list, or how I suppose to do this update instead of this?

[UPDATE]

So I moved my list from my state class to viewModel like this:

```
    private val _list = MutableStateFlow(listOf<UserWithRoleView>())
    val list = _list.asStateFlow()

In the screen class, I used as normal: 

val listState = viewModel.list.collectAsState()
```

Surprisingly it worked, so re-composition happened every time when I changed the role property.

I also added a List variable to my state class, just for experimentation, and when I updated that list, re-composition happened again.

So now, I'm totally confused what's problem with my list, but I think now not the list the problem, but the my data class, which looks like this

```
    data class UserWithRoleView(
    val id: String,
    val userName: String,
    val email: String,
    val role: RoleEnum,
    var newRole: RoleEnum
) {
    fun mapToUserWithRoleDto() =
        UserWithRoleDto(
            id = id,
            userName = userName,
            email = email,
            role = newRole.name
        )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I have found the solution.

Till now, I updated the property of the list object, and assigned the list to the state. As you can see above.

If I create a new object, with the updated property, and replace the old list item to the new one, then the screen will be recomposed. I do it like this:

```
val index = _state.value.userList.indexOfFirst { it.id == user.id }

    val list = _state.value.userList.toMutableList()
    list[index] = list[index].copy(
        newRole = role
    )

    _state.update { userManagerState ->
        userManagerState.copy(
            userList = list
        )
    }
```

I don't really understand, why does it work only just in this way.